# How to read a URL into an AVURLAsset

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, uistoryboardsegue

I am trying to create an AVURLAsset like so:

```
class TrimFootageViewController: UIViewController {
    var movieURL:URL?

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        playerView.playerLayer.player = player

        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.thumbnailImage = setThumbnailFrom(path: movieURL!)
        print(type(of: self.movieURL!))     
        asset = AVURLAsset(url: self.movieURL!, options: nil)
        print(asset ?? "couldn't get asset")

    }
```

This does not work throwing an Error (lldb) on a another class: Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x100318b4c). Additionally it doesn't print the asset so I don't believe its being set right.

However when I use:

```
class TrimFootageViewController: UIViewController {
        var movieURL:URL?

        override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            playerView.playerLayer.player = player

            super.viewWillAppear(animated)
            self.thumbnailImage = setThumbnailFrom(path: movieURL!)
            print(type(of: self.movieURL!))  
            guard let movieURL = URL(string: "https://devimages-cdn.apple.com/samplecode/avfoundationMedia/AVFoundationQueuePlayer_HLS2/master.m3u8") else {
            return
             }   
            asset = AVURLAsset(url: movieURL, options: nil)
            print(asset ?? "couldn't get asset")

        }
```

it works and correctly prints `<AVURLAsset: 0x101b00210, URL = https://devimages-cdn.apple.com/samplecode/avfoundationMedia/AVFoundationQueuePlayer_HLS2/master.m3u8>`

self.movieURL! and movieURL both have the same type of URL when printed. Also note that I am settings self.movieURL like so in the previous controller's segue:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
        if segue.identifier == "TrimFootage_Segue" {
            let controller = segue.destination as! TrimFootageViewController
            controller.movieURL = self.videoRecorded
        }
    }
```

how do I properly set the movieURL asset in the AVURLAsset call such that it can be instantiated?

Comment: I'm sorry, but for clarity, it doesn't crash in this class, but in another class? What code crashes, there?

Comment: @NateBirkholz it crashes in the first viewWillAppear function where I set         asset = AVURLAsset(url: self.movieURL!, options: nil). It does not crash when in the second function linked when I set the movieURL from an external link

Comment: Have you tried "var movieURL = "https://devimages-cdn.apple.com/samplecode/avfoundationMedia/AVFoundationQueuePlayer_HLS2/master.m3u8""

Comment: does `print(type(of: self.movieURL!))` log "URL" in the first case? just checking...

Comment: @staticVoidMan yes it does

Comment: @Vanya it says: Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'URL'

Comment: @BigBoy1337 do you get your AVURLAsset from the PhotoLibrary or is it from a recording?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at your code it seems like `movieURL` is filePath as `setThumbnailFrom(path: movieURL!)` is working fine. May be this could be the reason.

**You can avoid crashing by applying `if-let` check as:**

```
class TrimFootageViewController: UIViewController {
    var movieURL: URL?

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        playerView.playerLayer.player = player   

        // Just check whether self.movieURL is filePath or URL
        // For "setThumbnailFrom" passing as file path
        // For "AVURLAsset(url: movURL, options: nil)" passing as URL

        self.thumbnailImage = setThumbnailFrom(path: self.movieURL!) // Passing as filePath 

        if let movURL = self.movieURL as? URL, let asset = AVURLAsset(url: movURL, options: nil) {
            print(asset)
        } else {
            print("Not able to load asset")
        }
    }
}
```

**Make sure you are sending `URL` from previous screen:**

```
let controller = segue.destination as! TrimFootageViewController
controller.movieURL = self.videoRecorded
```

Answer (score 1):

1. In `TrimFootageViewController` , define a `var movieURLString = ""`.
2. In the previous controller's segue:
   set `movieURLString` instead of `movieURL`.
3. Then, use your second way init `movieURL`.

Maybe ok.

Answer (score 1):

> I have updated your code. Please have a look. It will not crash anymore and also please check that you are sending the URL(it cannot be nil) from the previous controller:

```
class TrimFootageViewController: UIViewController {
    var movieURL: URL?

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        playerView.playerLayer.player = player

        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        if let mURL = movieURL {
        self.thumbnailImage = setThumbnailFrom(path: mURL)
        print(type(of: mURL))     
        asset = AVURLAsset(url: mURL, options: nil)
        print(asset ?? "couldn't get asset")
        }    
    }
```